# Php strtotime not showing the valid date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i have a mysql table with column type DATETIME, i want it to display like 19 Aug, 2013.
so i have tried with

```
echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br/>';
echo date('y  M ,Y',strtotime($date));
```

The output im getting is

```
2013-08-19 22:47:12
13 Aug ,2013
```

The i tried with

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-08-19');
echo $datetime->format('yM,Y');
```

But it also outputs the wrong date 13Aug,2013 
Any one have faced the same kind of issue.

Comment: dont, use the mysql function DATE_FORMAT instead

Comment: The Output you are getting is conform to the pattern you use - so wheres the problem? Check your pattern! It would have been faster than creating this post. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

`y` is two-digit year, you want `d`, which is day. See also the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: hi, i get the answer , which i changed 'y  M ,Y ' to 'd  M ,Y' .    echo date('d  M ,Y',strtotime('2013-08-19 22:47:12'));

Answer (score 0):

You used `y` twice:

```
echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br/>';
echo date('d  M ,Y',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like it's doing exactly what it should - but the format specifier you are passing to date() and dateTime->format() looks strange - 'y' returns the year as 2 digits, 'Y' returns a 4 digit year. Did you mean that you wanted the day of the month at the start of he output?

[Try 'd' or 'j' in place of 'y'.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)